# F# mutable function arguments

Tags: f#

Is there a way to have mutable function arguments in F#, that would allow something like

```
let mutable i = 9

let somefun n = n <- 12; ()

somefun i

(* *not* a real-world example *)
```

I do understand that this can be made to work by wrapping it into a record type

```
type SomeRec = { mutable i: int }

let ri = { i = 9 }

let someotherfun r = r.i <- 12; ()
```

and that this can be done in a similar fashion for class members. However, even after browsing through the whole F# Language Specification (yes, I did!), there seems to be no syntax to allow the first case, and the compiler appears to be quite unhappy about my trying this. I was hoping there would be some sort of type annotation, but mutable cannot be used in such.

I also know that I should not be doing this sort of thing in the first place, but the first case (`int` binding) and the second (`record` type) are semantically identical, and any such objection would hold for both cases equally.

So I think that I am missing something here.

Comment: If you need to mutate your params, you're still thinking imperatively. Can you describe exactly what you're trying to do, maybe someone can suggest a more idiomatic solution instead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use ref as arguments

```
let v = ref 0
let mutate r = 
    r := 100
mutate v
printfn "%d" !v
```

Or byref keyword

```
let mutable v = 0
let mutate (r : byref<_>) = 
    r <- 100
mutate &v
printfn "%d" v
```

Comment: Note the `byref` is like C# `ref`.  If you need C# `out`, then use `byref` but also add the `[<System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out>]` attribute to the parameter.

Comment: This answer is technically correct, but I would cringe seeing it used in practice. OP should stick to F# idioms instead of trying to write C# in a little different syntax.

Comment: @Juliet This can be a *lot* faster than the functional equivalent in F#. I've used this in production code.

Comment: @JD @Julient - Seems that ```byref<..>``` is needed if you are going to have an ```[<Out>]``` mutable result type for calling from C# to F# as seen here: https://musingstudio.com/2017/02/17/how-to-extend-f-discriminated-unions-for-use-from-c/comment-page-1/?unapproved=14947&moderation-hash=e7e536aee0cec658f39a04dfc3d2e934#comment-14947

Please, it would be great to learn a more F#-ish way to call from C# v7.0.3 (.NET 2) to F#.  Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Use `byref` keyword which is equivalent to C# `ref`.
See [Passing by reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/parameters-and-arguments#passing-by-reference).

Comment: Oh dear, there are still quite basic bits I am missing. I guess it's back to reading the whole thing *again*. Sorry, I can only mark one 'accepted' answer, but will vote this one up.

Comment: I just found Jon Skeet's article on parameters passing in another topic: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html It's on C#, but this is just what you need now.